# How to use role in authguard to protect routes?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a application and i'm checking for authorisation to protecting `route` using `AuthGuard`.
Now i want to protect my child routes with autguard based on role system which i'm getting response from backend while logging in. If role is `admin` i will allow him to view all routes. If role is `user` i want him to access only `notification` route. I tried using `*ngIf` but i will hide only route, but when user enter `URL` it will be redirecting

`auth.guard.ts`

```
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

    const isAuth = this.authService.getIsAuth();
    if (!isAuth) {
      this.router.navigate(['/sign-in']);
    }
    return isAuth;
  }
```

`roleAuth.guard.ts`

```
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

    const role = this.authService.role();
    if (role ==='Admin') {
     //got  stuck here
    }
   if (role ==='moderator') {
     //got  stuck here
    }
   if (role ==='user') {
     //got  stuck here
    }
    return role;
  }
```

`app-routing.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: SideNavComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },

      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('./components/sidenav/pages/dashboard/dashboard.module')
          .then(m => m.DashboardModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'notifications',
        loadChildren: () => import('./components/sidenav/pages/notifications/notifications.module')
          .then(m => m.NotificationsModule)
      },

    ],
  },

];
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a RoleAdminGuard and use canActivate / canLoad for `dashboard` route. Something like this

`role-admin.guard.ts`

```js
canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
    const isAdmin = this.authService.getAuth().role === 'ADMIN';
    if (isAdmin) {
      this.router.navigate(['/notifications']);
    }
    return isAdmin;
}
```

`app-routing.module.ts`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: SideNavComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },

      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        canLoad: [RoleAdminGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('./components/sidenav/pages/dashboard/dashboard.module')
          .then(m => m.DashboardModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'notifications',
        loadChildren: () => import('./components/sidenav/pages/notifications/notifications.module')
          .then(m => m.NotificationsModule)
      },

    ],
  },

];
```

Comment: Can you explain me a little bit more in my code. I'm still in learning stage for my first job after my grad. Your explanation would be helpful for me to understand more in detail

Comment: I just edited my answer to add RoleAdminGuard with canLoad in dashboard child route

Comment: Can I use it for nested childs too. If i have n routes only admin can access all routes. Let's say we have 4 role. Role `Admin, user, moderator, user2`. `Moderator` can view only some routes and `user` can view only his route and `user2 `can view his route only. Don't we have anything like `role:[Admin,user2]`. Do we need to implement different authguards?

Comment: There is no correct answer for all situation. A guard can be reused, but for multiple roles, you have possibilites: Guard factory with roles parameters, a guard for each combination with a common check method with parameters,a sole guard which takes route data as parameters ...

Comment: Thanks i got some kind of fix for now. Still lot to explore.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario i guess you have to apply child level route restrictions, In order to do that you have to split your project in to feature module architecture
[Angular Guide for feature module](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules). once you do this change you can simply apply your [Authguard] on to child routes in side your feature module routing.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ClientDashboardComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'edit/:id',
        component: ClientEditComponent,
        canActivateChild: [AuthorizeGuard],
        data: { roles: [PermissionCodes.ClientProfile_Write] },
        canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]
    } ]
```

just like this you can restrict your child route even you enter url in new tab. hope this will help for you

Comment: I'm looking for similar kind of solution. But i don't know to implement  canActivateChild: [AuthorizeGuard],
        data: { roles: [PermissionCodes.ClientProfile_Write] },
        canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]. How can i get the role to my app module?

Comment: In my case all the routes will be children of `Dashboard`. let's say `notification` will also have children routes. Now i wanna give roles to each route. `Dashboard` can be seen by everyone

Comment: its basically similar to the authGuard. this is an Interface that a class can implement to be a guard deciding if a child route can be activated. you can pass your own logic in to [AuthorizeGuard] in order to restrict child route. but i recommand to use same authguard for both parent and child routs

Comment: are you putting all routes in app-routing.module.ts ? in order to achieve this you have to maintain feature level routing file. as i mentioned earlier. seems  to be you have only one main module in tour project

Comment: Actually i'm using feature level routing

Comment: just follow that angular guide and refer thsi link for CanActivateChild feature.                          https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateChild

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215797/discussion-between-sai-and-codemind).